# Display Value of a chossen ListItem from a DropDownList in VB

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using VB and have a DropDownList that I want the Value displayed as an integer.  So if the user chooses 15, then the display is 'Size: 300'

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="AppList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="110px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1000">15-1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="500">15-2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="300">15</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Size:

Comment: This is not what a DropDownList does. The text of an option should stay the same regardless of whether the user has selected it.

Comment: I don't want to change anything.  If a user chooses the text 15, I want to display it's value of 300.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to use a [code render block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx) to display the selected value:

```
Size: <%= AppList.SelectedValue %>
```

Of course, there are plenty of other options.  e.g. You could use a label with a [data-binding expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100).aspx), but this will require a call to `Page.DataBind()`:

```
Size: <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# AppList.SelectedValue %>" />

' In code-behind
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Page.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a label or a literal containing the "Size: []" (lets call it "SizeLabel"), just create an event on SelectedIndexChanged of your DropDownList with id="AppList". In that block of code...

```
Dim SelectedValue As Integer = Me.AppList.SelectedValue
Me.SizeLabel.Text = "Size: " & SelectedValue
```

When the selected index of the DropDownList changes, the value that is selected is displayed on the label.